# ImageView animation - show image gradually

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I want to perform the following:

Place 2 images on top of each other, occasionally hide the upper image to display the one below it.

When I remove the upper image I want to animate it out as a layer removal.

I want to remove the most bottom/lowest line, then remove the second most lowest line and so on. I dont want to move/slide the image upwards... any suggestions on how this could be done using ImageView's and animations?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of 'line' you want to remove then what u can do is u can keep a set of empty textview over the image which are initially hidden...now start a thread and start making those textview visible and after making one textview as visible u can use sleep() for few milliseconds which will give look like animation. At the end when all texviews are visible once again start making them invisible while change the image view with new image...